# Icon inside Leaflet control layer does not display?

Tags: leaflet

I created a leaflet control layer to switch between two base maps (Bing and OpenCycleMap), Yet I don't see the icon inside the layer control:

```
var baseMaps = {
             "Bing": bingLayer,
              "OpenCycleMap": tileLayer
         };
        L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);
```

The result in the navigator:

[image]

Is there any special config to add the layer icon instead of the blank space? As I know this icon should be by default displayed.

Answer (score 4):

The only explanation for this would be that required icon image is missing. It is either `layers.png` or `layers-2x.png` and should be in subfolder `images` of folder where leaflet style sheet `leaflet.css` is located.

You can check this with browser developer tools (F12, network section). If icon is really missing you will get 404 status for icon image file.

Comment: it is actually missing I checked it. I added the folder images but still the problem persists. I did use cdn but no remarkable change.

Comment: Did you check in browser developer tools (F12, network section) the location from where browser tries to download the image?